# Can't fill my roster. Can't buy players

Tags: madden-25

How do I move on from here. Ideally I would restart the team from scratch with 0 coins and try again however there is no clear means of resetting the team. How does it get accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with EA customer support it is clear there is no way out. You cannot reset your account. You must spend money to buy packs in order to hopefully fill that roster slot if you do not have the remaining points to acquire someone through other means.

The chat support is moderately incompetent so if you are in North America with questions it is highly recommended to call during their primary customer support hours as these individuals seem to have actually played the games where as the online chat support individuals often do not seem to have ever gamed.